# Selenium4: "The method newWindow(WindowType) is undefined for the Type WebDriver.TargetLocator"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, new-window, selenium4

I'm trying to play with the Selenium 4 features in eclipse with java but can't seem to get them to work, which i'm assuming must be my mistake in configuration, so I'd appreciate if anyone can explain where i'm going wrong and how I can correct it?

Code below: I get an error warning on the last line (containing the newWindow() method) and the error message is as per the Title of this post.
I've downloaded the selenium-java-4.0.0-alpha-4 from here https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=4.0-alpha4/
i've created a new eclipse java project, and unzipped and included all of the jar files in my java build path, but it doesn't seem to recognise / or be able to find the newWindow() method

```
package practice;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import static org.openqa.selenium.support.locators.RelativeLocator.withTagName;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class Sel4alpha4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB); // this line has the error 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**There might be two problems:**

**1) Incorrect Import- You should import the following:**

`org.openqa.selenium.WindowType;`

**2) Issue with the version you are using. Try to upgrade the selenium version.**

**Version:**

```
selenium 4.0.0-beta-4
```

Please try to download the updated jar from the below link:

https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

or

https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=4.0-beta-4/